# IBM Cloud Functions "Failed to pull container image"

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions, container-registry, ibm-iam

I have a docker container that I want to run in IBM Cloud Functions (OpenWhisk), because I don't want the container to be publicly accessible I want to store it in the IBM Cloud Container Registry. For OpenWhisk to be able to access it I followed this tutorial for a similar problem: [Access IAM-based services from IBM Cloud Functions](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/accessing-iam-based-services-from-ibm-cloud-functions/)

To summarize the steps:

1. create a IAM Namespace for Functions
2. give the namespace access to
   the container registry

[image: IAM Namespace]

But sadly this doesn't solve the problem, I still get `Failed to pull container image 'uk.icr.io/hvdveer/e2t-bridge:0.1.4'`. And I can't really find any points where I could configure an API key or something.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

OpenWhisk (the underlying technology of IBM Cloud Functions) does not yet support authenticated access to a registry. As a consequence, AFAIK your use-case is currently not supported.

Comment: Ah that's disappointing. I had found a similar statement in 2018 but I hoped the IAM Namespace would solve it.  Do you know of a different way I could run some code periodically in IBM Cloud?

Comment: IBM Cloud Functions (Apache OpenWhisk) does support deploying an action from a custom Docker image and a zip archive. This means public dependencies can be baked into the new public runtime image on Docker Hub and private source code made available through the zip archive. Does this allow you to use Cloud Functions for the app?